# Error starting ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

I have installed *Node.js* to start with an *ionic* project.
I have also installed *ionic* and *cordova* using the commands below:

```
npm install ionic -g 
npm install cordova -g
```

I am using the command below to create an *ionic* project:

```
ionic start myApp blank
```

And i m getting the following error:

```
D:\IonicWork>ionic start myApp blank
Creating Ionic app in folder D:\IonicWork\myApp based on blank project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error with start Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.121:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
Error Initializing app: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.121:443
 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.121:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
Caught exception:
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.121:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
```

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Malini

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a company network, you are most probably behind a corporate web proxy. There are plenty of solution out there.

For a headstart, you need to add `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables based on the proxy you got from your company IT department.

Open your node command prompt in administrator mode and run following command. After that, close and restart your node command prompt and try to run `ionic start` again.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to start  in `ionic creator`.and its the better place for design also